# How do I fix Directus error code 3 when downloading stored files

Tags: directus

I can store files to the specified storage location via the GUI.  I can see the files are in the storage location.

When I try to download them using the GUI, I get this every time.

```
{"error":{"code":3,"message":"Unauthorized request","class":"Directus\\Exception\\UnauthorizedException","file":"\/var\/www\/directus\/src\/helpers\/app.php","line":287}}
```

When I try the links from the File library, I get the same error.

I found some old topics concerning a "_" project.  I do not see any "_" entries in my project.php configuration.

Everyone has read permissions for the storage directory.

The rest of the system appears to run without error.

Answer (score 0):

check the folder in the server and what is been set, the default should be, like

[image]

So then if you want to access the 300x300 the URL should be like:

domain.com/public/uploads/Directus/generated/w300,h300,fcrop,q80/file-name.jpg